# Disposition of xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04 in system upgraded to 20.04

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, upgrade, xorg

I've been upgrading some 18.04 systems to 20.04 and in general it's going well.  But some of the systems have a package `xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04` still installed after the upgrade.  My thought was to replace it with `xserver-xorg-hwe-20.04` but there doesn't seem to be such a package.

So...I don't know what to do with this package. Is just removing it safe (according to `synaptic` it has no dependants)? Or forget about it?

Comment: I identify after an distro upgrade obsolete (not longer available packages) with `apt-show-versions | grep avail` and remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packages.ubuntu.com [says](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04) that this *`xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04`* package is transitional on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and that it has size of 9 Kb.

So it may be safely removed by

```
sudo apt-get purge --autoremove xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
```

This package was needed on 18.04 LTS to get newer components of [HWE stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack?highlight=%28xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04%29#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_-_Bionic_Beaver).

About the *`xserver-xorg-hwe-20.04`* package you are right - [it does not exist](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=xserver-xorg-hwe-20.04&searchon=names).

Comment: I finally got around to doing this. It did not cause any problems. Thanks for the answer.